# Objective C, NSMutableDictionary reference count

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

```
    NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [nodeAttributes objectForKey:UUID];//nodeAttributes is NSMutalbleDictionary
    if (attrs == nil) {
         attrs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
         [nodeAttributes setObject:attrs forKey:UUID];
         [attrs release];
    }
```

I am not sure this code will works...Should I have something like this instead of this

```
    NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [nodeAttributes objectForKey:UUID];//nodeAttributes is NSMutalbleDictionary
    if (attrs == nil) {
         attrs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
         [nodeAttributes setObject:[attrs retain] forKey:UUID];
         [attrs release];
    }
```

I am not sure if setObject method will increase the reference count...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSMutableDictionary's `setObject` will retain the object (this is [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableDictionary)), so the first bit of code is correct and the second leaks. Style-wise, it may be more clear to a reader to do the following:

```
if (attrs == nil) {
     attrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
     [nodeAttributes setObject:attrs forKey:UUID];
}
```

Although memory-management-wise, your approach is probably better in that it avoids (implicitly) using autorelease.

Answer (score 2):

The retain count will be incremented in the first case. That's the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are responsible for claiming ownership of the things they own. So yes, `setObject:forKey:` will retain. This is explained in detail (but still very briefly) in Apple's [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

setObject will send a retain message so you don't need to do that.